# Writing data to Firestore using Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have added a trigger which works whenever a new record is added to a specified path.

My code:

```
exports.modifyNewForm = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}/form_fillers/{filler}/forms/{form_id}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const newValue = snap.data();


      const first_name = "James";
      const last_name =  "Alex";
      const newPhone = 100;

    // Parameters
      const userId = context.params.userId;
      const filler_1 = context.params.filler;
      const form_id = context.params.form_id;

    const userRef = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).collection("form_fillers").doc(filler_1);

     console.log("new form" + newValue)

 return userRef.get().then(parentSnap => {
        const user = parentSnap.data();
        const phone = user.phone
    if(typeof phone === "undefined") {
                 console.log("OP 1 executed");

              return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).collection('form_fillers').doc(filler_1).set({first_name:first_name, last_name:last_name,phone:newPhone}, {merge: true}).then(writeResult => {
        console.log("New write: " + writeResult);
    });

        } else {

             console.log("OP 2 executed");

             return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).collection('form_fillers').doc(filler_1).set({first_name:first_name, last_name:last_name,phone: user.phoneID}, {merge: true}).then(writeResult => {
        console.log("New write: " + writeResult);
    });

        } 
    }); 

});
```

Ok so in this code, I'm trying to achieve this:

1. Whenever a new form is added, the function triggers ✅
2. Read the `filler` data and check if there's a phone number, I have used `typeof` to check if the field exists in Firestore, If not. Set the `filler`'s phone number to `100`. But if exists, update it with the newly submitted forms field which is `phoneID`

What is not working:

1. this code works till the `console.log("new form" + newValue)` line and i don't get a print for neither of the following `if` statement. There's no `OP 1 executed` or `OP 2 executed` in the logs.

   2. there's a `phone` field with value of `0` in my database generated randomly.

I'm new to JS and your help is appreciated

Comment: What does the log say in the Firebase console for Cloud Functions?  If there's a problem, it will appear there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your "userRef.get()" promise is somehow failing. You could add a catch at the end and do a console log in there to see what the error is, like:

```
return userRef.get().then(
   ...
)
.catch(
  error => console.log('The error is:', error)
);
```